# Print out first part of user specified length

Tags: java, input, while-loop

I am trying to print out the amount of letters that the user specifies. For e.g. user types in a word-Horse and specify the number of letters they want to print out- 4. The output should say Result: Hors. I have to use the sub string method.

My program gets rid of the letters that the user specified and prints out the rest. How can I fix this?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FirstPart {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Type a word: ");
    String word = reader.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Length of the first part: ");
    int firPar = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());

    int i = 0;

    while (i <= firPar) {

        System.out.print("Result: " + word.substring(firPar));
        i++;
        break;
    }

}
```

}

Comment: I recommend you to read the doc of substring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably use [`Scanner.nextInt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt%28%29) and you don't need a loop at all. Just call [`String.substring(int, int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29) from `0` to `firPar` like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Type a word: ");
    String word = reader.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Length of the first part: ");
    int firPar = reader.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Result: " + word.substring(0, firPar));
}
```

Comment: Thank you. That worked just fine. I was over complicating things. Any reason as to why use nextInt() instead of Integer.parseInt()?

Comment: @NoahKettler You already have the `Scanner` and it can do it for you. I think it's cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.print("Result: " + word.substring(0, firPar));
```

If you only specify one int for substring it is the starting index (inclusive).  If you specify 2 ints it is starting index (inclusive) ending index (exclusive).  Also you can get rid of your while loop.

```
substring(startIndex) //will take startIndex to length

substring(startIndex, endIndex) //will take startIndex (inclusive) to endIndex (exclusive)
```